# Call Python function from PHP and pass an array

Tags: php, python

I am new In Python,
How can I call a function of python from `PHP` and pass an array as an argument.

This is what I did so far,

```
$result = exec('C:\Python27\python.exe D:\wamp\www\python.py\get_player_list',$out);
echo var_dump($out);die;
```

I am able to call python file from PHP,But I am not sure how to call function and pass it an argument.

Here is my python.py file:

```
def get_player_list(possible_name):
    print 'test'
```

I have an PHP array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Player_Name] => Russell Westbrook
            [position] => PG
            [salary] => 11000
            [point] => 53.47
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Player_Name] => Chris Paul
            [position] => PG
            [salary] => 10200
            [point] => 45.52
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [Player_Name] => Antonio 
            [position] => PG
            [salary] => 10221
            [point] => 43.52
        )
)
```

Comment: I want to pass PHP array to python

Comment: Unless there are implicit assumptions about the data in PHP arrays which I'm ont familiar with, your array can contain non-serializable data which you'll **have to serialize** (to JSON, for example). If it is serializable as arguments you can get away with less effort, but I have no idea what you're passing.

Comment: PHP's "arrays" are effectively arbitrary data structures. Reut is asking what your array _contains_ and how it is _structured_. This is important, because we need a better understanding of what the inputs to the Python program might be. Is it a simple array like `array(1, 2, 3)` or something more complex? Does it contain any objects?

Comment: I just update my question for how my php array look like.
I just want to pass my this array to python

Comment: @user5320720, that looks like it will serialize to JSON nicely. Use PHP's [`json_encode`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to generate the JSON. Pass that to your Python script either as a file or even directly on the command-line and use [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) in Python to parse it.